# Are there any creatures that have more than one "creature type"?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

I was wondering whether in the official published materials, or in Unearthed Arcana, there are any creatures that have multiple types (for instance, creatures that in their description it says they are both Fey and Beast).

I appreciate any examples of such creatures - or, if none exist, confirmation that creatures only have the *one* classification of monster type and that's it.

Answer (score 13):

### There are currently no monsters with more than one creature type

The *Monster Manual* (page 7) includes a list of all creature types (cutting out the descriptions):

> Aberrations, Beasts, Celestials, Constructs, Dragons, Elementals, Fey, Fiends, Giants, Humanoids, Monstrosities, Oozes, Plants, and Undead

After a rather large amount of scrolling through the results pages on [dndbeyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters) I have come to the conclusion that there do not exist any monsters with multiple creature types.

There are creatures, like the [Quasit](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/quasit), that are shapechangers, or are a specific subset of a type (in this case a Quasit is a fiend, but more specifically, a demon); however, shapechanger is not a creature type in and of itself, nor is demon. Similarly a [Swarm of Bats](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/swarm-of-bats) has the creature type Beast, it being a swarm doesn't change that.

There are also creatures like the [Tanarukk](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/tanarukk), a fiend (demon) *and* an Orc, except Orc is not a creature type, Humanoid is, but the Tanarukk are not humanoids. The description of this creature includes the following:

> [...] The demon lord Baphomet gladly shares the secret of creating tanarukks with those who entreat him for power. The process corrupts an unborn orc of the tribe, transforming it at birth into a creature much more savage than an orc [...]

Despite there not existing any *monsters* with multiple creature types, there are unpublished *races* with multiple creature types. For example, the [Unearthed Arcana Centaurs and Minotaurs](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/centaurs-and-minotaurs) ([pdf direct link](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/UA-Centaur.pdf)) include the following feature:

> **Hybrid Nature.** You have two creature types: humanoid and monstrosity. You can be affected by a game effect if it works on either of your creature types.

Notably the later officially published versions of these races do *not* have multiple creature types. So outside of this Unearthed Arcana I do not know of any creatures (NPC or PC) that have multiple creature types. I also do not know any way of adding a creature type onto an already existing creature without removing the one they currently have.

Comment: Minor note - once the material from Unearthed Arcana gets published, UE version is no longer supposed to be considered a part of the game and should not be used.

Comment: [This spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aWM7eVmAK5Rinq2jA9Ev2B5ZontMx-5cuN8vyaQujik/edit#gid=0) lists every monster appearing in the 3 monster manuals. There are no dual-typed creatures in them.

Comment: I think the reason that some monsters had a special "also counts as [X]" in previous editions is because certain creature types had certain inherent abilities by default (undead/plants/constructs are always immune to mind-affecting effects and sneak attacks, outsiders can't be res'd, etc.), so an undead that also counted as an outsider would by default have the inherent benefits of both. This is something they moved away from in particular in 5e.