# Does Arcane Abjuration affect a Tiefling or Aasimar?

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric, tiefling, aasimar

The Arcana cleric's Arcane Abjuration feature may affect a celestial, elemental, fey, or fiend.

A Tiefling has infernal heritage and an Aasimar has celestial heritage.  Is this sufficient for them to be  affected by Arcane Abjuration?

Comment: Related: [Can a Paladin sense a Tiefling?](/questions/59154)

Answer (score 20):

#### No, because tieflings and aasimars are humanoids.

According to the [basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/step-by-step-characters#1ChooseaRace), player races (such as tiefling or aasimar) are assumed to be humanoid.

> Every character belongs to a race, one of the many intelligent humanoid species in the D&D world.

Humanoid is a separate creature type than fiend or celestial. There are [no creatures with multiple types](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/164838/).  Therefore tieflings do not count as fiends, and aasimars do not count as celestials.

Some humanoids have subtypes, however "fiend" is not a valid subtype for humanoids.  For example, a tiefling NPC would count as "humanoid (tiefling)".

Comment: Can a creature be 2 types, such as humanoid and fiend, in the same way that a creature can be a humanoid and an elf (with numerous sub-types)?

Comment: @CWallach  Yes, a creature can be a hybrid for example UA Centaurs/Minotaurs are both humanoid and monstrosity, but as MikeQ says, this does not apply to Aasimar or Tiefling characters.

Comment: What is the logic for a hybrid humanoid/monstrosity but not a hybrid humanoid/fiend?

Comment: @CWallach: That's something only the designers can answer. All we can say is that tieflings and aasimar are not fiends or celestials respectively; mechanically, their type is just humanoid.

Comment: @CWallach In the past (3rd Edition), they  made the distinction - Aasimar and Tieflings were "Native Outsiders". They were affected by things that affected outsiders (a broad type that included celestials, fiends, devils, *and* elementals), but still counted the Prime Material as their home plane for things that might send them away or work differently on home-vs-foreign planes. For 5E, they were made humanoids, probably to simplify player characters - the game is no longer strongly typed.